# WebHttpBinding in WCF: how to configure it the proper way?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, app-config, webhttpbinding

Trying to follow this example to make it work: http://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/archive/2008/10/08/wcf-using-webhttpbinding-for-rest-services.aspx

Here is my `App.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>      
      <!-- The service for the TEST WEB client -->
      <service name="MyServer.AAServiceType" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
         <endpoint address="testservice" 
                   binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
                   contract="MyServer.AAIContractName" />
         <host>
            <baseAddresses>
               <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8787/" />
            </baseAddresses>
         </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
          <!-- TEST WEB BEHAVIOR -->
          <behavior name="Default">
             <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
       <!-- TEST WEB ENDPOINT -->
       <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="webBehavior">
             <webHttp />
          </behavior>
       </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Update:** The service contract is:

```
namespace MyServer
{
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.NotAllowed)] 
    public interface IContractName 
    { 
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "date/{year}/{month}/{day}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)] 
        [OperationContract] 
        string GetDate(string day, string month, string year); 
    }

    public class ServiceType : IContractName 
    {  
        public string GetDate(string day, string month, string year) 
        { 
           return new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year), Convert.ToInt32(month), Convert.ToInt32(day)).ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy"); 
        } 
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I am trying to connect to 8787 port (using `putty`, for instance) a *"Connection refused"* error is returned. As you can see, I've also tried to put the wrong names in contract class and service implementation and got no exceptions. What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: Can you show us your service contract?? What kind of URL template are you specifying?

Comment: Sure. Kindly see the update. Also stopped the locally installed IIS (via the UI console) to make sure that noone intercepts the HTTP requests.

Comment: Okay, problem found - supplied the answer of my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an error in the code that launched the service. The correct code is:

```
using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceType)))
{
    try
    {
      // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages.
      serviceHost.Open();

      // The service can now be accessed.
      Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
      Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
      Console.ReadLine();

      // Close the ServiceHost.
      serviceHost.Close();
    }
    catch (CommunicationException commProblem)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(commProblem.Message);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, so with this, the URL `http://localhost:8787/testservice/date/2010/08/31` works??

Answer (score 1):

Are you hosting in IIS, or self-hosting??

If you're hosting this in IIS (using a *.svc file), then IIS dictates the address - it will be

```
http://yourserver/yourvirtualdirectory/yourservice.svc/.........
```

If you self-host, then everything seems OK to me - in that case, your base address comes into play:

```
http://localhost:8787/testservice
```

should be your service address now.

Comment: I am self-hosting. Tried both: to connect to the exactly the same URL you've suggested AND to connect just to the 8787 port with 'putty'. Failed either way.